# Email confirmation asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This my working method to send a email

```
       Sub emailConfirm()
    Dim email As String = txtMail.Text
    Dim name As String = txtPrenom.Text + txtNom.Text

    Dim mail As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
    'mail.To.Add("francois.smtp@gmail.com")
    mail.To.Add(email)
    mail.From = New MailAddress("sumerman@gmail.com.com")
    mail.Subject = "Email using Gmail"

    Dim Body As String = "Hi " + name + ", this mail is to confirm your registration" + "Click on    the link to confirm please" + " Link(check note)  "
    mail.Body = Body

    mail.IsBodyHtml = True
    Dim smtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("sumerman@gmail.com", "12345")
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    smtp.Send(mail)


End Sub
```

note:I want to send Link contains a unique identifier and verify the unique identifier in the login.aspx

I don't know when to do this...

I found nothing interesting on the net ...

This is in Vb.net

I will add security later

Thank's for your helping!

Comment: There's more to it than just a link.  All a link can do is send the user to your site.  How will your site handle the confirmation?  Maybe just link to your login page and treat the first successful login as confirmation?  Maybe store a time-sensitive key (if you want them to confirm within a given time window) and send them a link to a confirmation page with the key in the query string?

Comment: Side note: It _shouldn't_ even be remotely possible to include the password in the email.  You shouldn't _have_ the password.  You should have a hashed version of the password and should be hashing passwords on the login to compare with the stored hash.  Never, ever, ever store passwords in plain text.  Anywhere.  Ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off don't put the username and password in the email itself.  That's a bit sloppy.

Second, most sites now do the following:

1. User creates account
2. Email sent to user.  Link in email contains a unique identifier, not the username and password.
3. User clicks on link.  At this point the page tests to see if the unique id is valid.  If so, it tells them Thank You for confirming your account.  It then displays the login form.
4. User enters their login credentials.

Note that the email did NOT send the actual username/pw info.

Comment: Thank's but how to do the 2. and 3.

Comment: @FrankSharp: Upon creating the user record, you'd also create a unique ID (either as part of that record or an associated record) to store in the database.  That ID would be included as a query string parameter in the link in the email.  When a user visits a confirmation or login page and has such an ID on the query string, compare it with the ones stored in the database.  If found, account is confirmed.  If not found, redirect to an appropriate error.

Comment: thank's but can you give me a simple example of the "ID would be included as a query string parameter in the link in the email" Please